# Hide buttons based on size of li items using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to hide the `"next"` & `"prev"` button based on displaying of `list items`. If I've reached to the maximum list items, I should not be able to see again `"Next"` button, because that's the maximum and same for `"Prev"` button, if I reach to the initial point say to `1`, it should `hide`,

My code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var p;
    for(i=0;i<=$('#myList li').size(); i++){        
        p=i*20;
        $('#myList li:lt(5)').animate({"margin-left":"-"+p+"px"},1000).delay(5000);        

    }
    var $lis = $("#myList li").hide();
    $lis.slice(0, 5).show();
    var size_li = $lis.length;
    var x = 5,
    start = 0;
    $('#next').click(function () {
        if (start + x < size_li) {
            $lis.slice(start, start + x).hide();
            start += x;
            $lis.slice(start, start + x).show();            
            // Confused here
            if(parseInt(start) == 10) {
                $('#next').css('display','none');
            }
        }
    });
    $('#prev').click(function () {
        if (start - x >= 0) {
            $lis.slice(start, start + x).hide();
            start -= x;
            $lis.slice(start, start + x).show();
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/541/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var p;
    for(i=0;i<=$('#myList li').size(); i++){        
        p=i*20;
        $('#myList li:lt(5)').animate({"margin-left":"-"+p+"px"},1000).delay(5000);        

    }
 var $lis = $("#myList li").hide();
    $lis.slice(0, 5).show();
    var size_li = $lis.length;
    var x = 5,
        start = 0;
    $('#next').click(function () {
        if (start + x < size_li) {
            $lis.slice(start, start + x).hide();
            start += x;
            $lis.slice(start, start + x).show();            
            // Confused here
            if(parseInt(start) == 10) {
                $('#next').css('display','none');
            }
        }
        showHideButtons()
    });
    $('#prev').click(function () {
        if (start - x >= 0) {
            $lis.slice(start, start + x).hide();
            start -= x;
            $lis.slice(start, start + x).show();
        }
        showHideButtons();
    });
    function showHideButtons(){
        if (start == 0){
            $('#next').show();
            $('#prev').hide();
        }else if (start + x > size_li){
            $('#next').hide();
            $('#prev').show();
        }else{
            $('#next').show();
            $('#prev').show();
        } 
    }
    showHideButtons()
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/542/)